# Eclipse don't see metamodel classes

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, metamodel

I have metamodel class

```
import com.softserve.edu.model.Event_;
```

Eclipse say that he can't find this class, but when I compile with maven, it's all good, so I assume that Eclipse just don't see this classes.
What muse be done to fix this?

Comment: Do you have Maven support (m2e) installed?

Comment: It's integrated with eclipse already. Just checked.

Comment: Well, can you open that Type from the Navigate menu?